# Changing emotive wording in a factual document

Tags: professionalism, contractors

A colleague is putting together a PID ([Project Initiation Document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Initiation_Documentation)) to outline some issues with some of our IT architecture. She's a Project Management Team Lead, I'm an outside contractor brought in to a support an ageing system they have. This system relies in part on a second system from 2000. In her PID and other documents she repeatedly refers to it as being **unstable** and **rapidly** becoming more so.

To be clear, I absolutely agree with the aim of the project. The second system went out of the last bit of support in 2013 and it needs replacing in the firm. However this second system is no more stable or unstable than it was 3 years ago, or indeed 10 years ago.

I want to challenge her use of emotive wording in a technical document. What are some methods I could go about this and some wording suggestions I could make?

Comment: What's a PID? Why do you care how she words it? Why do you disagree with her assessment and are you qualified to do so?

Comment: Because if a document initiates change it should do so for reasons that are true. Yes, I am qualified. She is not.

Comment: It sounds like you could be arguing over semantics here and may be overthinking things. If the system no longer has any vendor support available but remains in productive use, then I would indeed call that an unstable system that well become a bigger liability ("more unstable") as time goes on because the risk of issues coming up increases and the knowledge of that system (internally or at external consultancies) dies out. Have you tried simply asking this colleague what she means by "unstable?"

Comment: Does *stable* have a well-defined, agreed upon meaning in this context? For example, we might define the stability of a server using metrics like uptime or response time. A user application that is *unstable* is usually one that crashes often or easily.

Comment: @Lilienthal I don't think the word unstable can be interpreted in that way within a PID. Whenever support on system disappears, the stability is not in question. It will always be exactly the same for as long nothing changes. However, the "risk" of using this system will increase. Stability refers to the system remaining functional as expected without problems. I find it VERY hard to contest this meaning of the word. You CAN contest what degree of stability is considered stable. regardless, there should always be a list of explained words. It should be in there if there's a different meaning.

Comment: @Migz A legacy system that cannot be updated meets your definition of unstable in my opinion as well as the classic definition of being unpredictable and failure-prone and that's why I mentioned that this is arguing over semantics. This entire question reeks of over-documentation. An analysis of whether a system is future proof shouldn't require a custom dictionary. But I suppose that this is neither the time nor place to start up a discussion on that.

Comment: What makes you say the system is 'no more unstable'? If it hasn't been receiving updates for 10 years and especially if it's on dedicated and aging hardware, I'd say the system is 'more unstable', it's likelihood of failure has definitely increased. I agree emotional words should be left out of a PID, but in this case I think the subjective wording is valuable in explaining the problem to non-technical management who will need to bankroll the upgrade.

Comment: @agentroadkill I think the problem is that the old system is not actually unstable (i.e. it does not have a high failure rate). It sounds like the correct term is "maintenance hazard". I.e., the system itself is stable but if it fails completely you are toast.

Comment: Have you discussed your concerns with her? Were you brought into the company to help with these PIDs?

Comment: @Brandin, I see your point and agree with it. I'd still say that the OP is splitting hairs. A PID is written for both technical and non-technical users. In my experience, if you tell management the system is stable, they will choose to wait until it is unstable (like waiting until the 'change oil' light comes on in your car). I think the 'unstable' terminology is better than trying to explain to management why hits 'stable' system needs a million-dollar overhaul or whatever the cost is.

Comment: @agentroadkill Why not just say it is unmaintained, or say the vendor has dropped support for the product(s)? In any case, if it was my colleague I would probably only mention it if she actually asked for feedback, or if it was actually my responsibility to check over the wording of the report.

Comment: I think there is also room for debate over how "emotive" the current words are. Could better words be chosen? Yes, but that is always true. Will these words cause trouble? Not if the document explains why the author comes to that conclusion, which it should be doing anyway. This feels like a basic exercise in "always define essential terms, since the reader may misunderstand them otherwise." Room for improvement, but not a disaster if it goes out unchanged; scale your response accordingly.

Comment: @Brandin, I agree about not bringing this up unless asked. I also like keshlam's point about defining terms. It may be that the OP and his colleague actually mean the same thing. In any case, I *would* call an unsupported, 10-year old system unstable - it may not 'go down' often, but it will almost certainly be non-standards compliant, running on legacy hardware etc. I think the goal is clarity, not technical correctness in this instance. **Edit** 'unmaintained' or unsupported isn't a problem in-and-of itself. In a PID, you'd want to make clear what that affects and why it needs to be fixed

Comment: Sounds like you are making an issue out of a non issue. Everybody agrees the system needs replacing. What does it matter the exact wording?

Comment: @Lilienthal the word stable when talking about a backend server is not semantics. Not at all.

Comment: @LokiAstari if we use the wrong reason to do the right thing today we might use the wrong reason to do a wrong thing tomorrow.

Comment: @Paul Now it's suddenly a server? Your post is talking about a system, not a machine. Words can have different meanings when they're applied to different things. You seem to be trying to apply objective rules to something as ill-defined as the English language, hence why I brought up that this is arguing semantics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with telling her directly that you aren't sure about your word choice. There's no need to beat around the bush. I would write an email, something along the lines of:

"Hi Debbie, thanks for writing the proposal for a project that is long overdue. We will all benefit from an update. However, I'm a bit worried about saying that it's "unstable" - this isn't technically accurate and I would hate to see this thrown out on a technicality. You never know what management will pick up on. Can we meet up to talk about another word to describe the system? Thanks. Paul."

Because there is an implicit criticism, I'd say an email is the less confrontational way of starting the conversation, but it should lead to a face-to-face conversation. If you have experience of submitting similar proposals you could bring that up too.

Comment: Note: saying "I'm not sure" is tremendously better than saying "you're wrong".

Answer (score 2):

> To be clear, I absolutely agree with the aim of the project.

**Since you agree, don't challenge her at all.**

Instead try to genuinely contribute to the system's modernizing.

Regardless how your system acts, fossilized systems should slowly and surely be removed. Especially when support is dropped.

It's a lot of work in the beginning, but afterwards it's really easier to go on with it.

Comment: By not talking to her at all about this she will risk repeating the same mistake over and over again. While in this case the ends justify the means. This will not be the case in other circumstances. Also, as an outside contractor, he is expected to deliver optimal quality work. This could reflect badly on him regardless of what the end result will be.

Answer (score 0):

Ask her "Why do we do this project?" and when she replies that it's unstable and is becoming more unstable just ask again "Is it really?". At that point she will need to think about it clearly and admit that it wouldn't describe the problem correctly. Once she understands that the description isn't accurate you can counter her with a suggestion such as the following:

- The system is no longer supported which increases the risk in case problems occur. The results of which we may or may not be capable of fixing due to having no support for this system.

I can assume that there may be more reasons, but as I read your question, this seems to be the most prevalent one.

It's important to keep asking questions about the PID. The PID is the core document to which nearly every question should be answered in. If the answers are incorrect or inaccurate your project will have a crooked base and may go into a unwanted direction. If you have a good PID, then any questions you may ask should be easy to answer and to defend in case you ask for her to elaborate on it.

If she insists on keeping it as unstable, ask her if the goal of the project is to make the project more stable, rather than more reliable and to reduce risks. If nothing works, ask for a second opinion from someone else in the company. possibly even your manager.

Worst case scenario, she will be as stubborn as an ox and tries to present it towards your manager. At this point it's 100% out of your hands. But I suspect that responsibility for the PID will shift towards you instead if it comes to it.

As a contractor you're hired to show your expertise and are expected to provide results. If you were to accept this PID you would be unable to show either. If in the end the manager still were to agree with her on the PID and the project were to fail due to this. You should have this documented that both she and the manager take responsibility for this part of the PID in case it goes wrong. (risk log entry)

Comment: I think your approach here is too aggressive. There's no point interrogating anyone. Also, your answer does not allow for the possibility of Jan changing his mind. His coworker may have her reasons.

Comment: @JK39 You misunderstand the meaning of a PID. It's a document that you can defend against any kind of questions. If she's capable of defending her PID from these questions she should be proud. However if it can't, it can have serious consequences. The only way that you can improve a PID is to keep asking questions towards it. I ask the same questions to myself in order to write my own PID. She's literally writing a contract for this project. That's what a PID is. I might be too blunt, however this is not something you want her to repeat. It's a risk if she does.

Comment: OK, but I suppose what I'm getting at is that you seem to be anticipating a combative conversation, which is a big assumption. Also your use of the Socratic method could create a teacher-student dynamic that she might respond negatively to.